# Check if has beign redirected from another controller

Tags: codeigniter

On my login controller or view I would like to be able to see if it is possible to check if page has redirected back to login and then display bootstrap error message. I also use a MY_controller function in codeigniter

I do not want to use codeigniter session flash data message. I have my own error message as showing in code.

**Is it possible to check if controller has been redirect from another controller?**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {        
        $data['title'] = 'Administration';

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        if (isset($user_id)) {
            $this->error['warning'] = "Working";
        } else {
            $this->error['warning'] = "";
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_validate');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('template/common/login.tpl', $data);

        } else {

            redirect('admin/dashboard');

        }

    }

    public function validate() {

        $this->load->library('user');

        if ($this->user->login() == FALSE) {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate', 'Does not match any of our database records');

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

MY Controller

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        Modules::run('admin/error/permission/check');
    }
}
```

Update I have tried This still displays message even though have not been redirect from another page.

Comment: `$this->load->library('user_agent'); $this->agent->referrer();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AdrienXL for some great advice. `$this->load->library('user_agent');` was the best method.

```
if ($this->agent->referrer()) {
    $this->error['warning'] = "Working";
} else {
        $this->error['warning'] = "";
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {        
        $data['title'] = 'Administration';

        $this->load->library('user_agent');

        if ($this->agent->referrer()) {
            $this->error['warning'] = "Working";
        } else {
            $this->error['warning'] = "";
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_validate');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('template/common/login.tpl', $data);

        } else {

            redirect('admin/dashboard');

        }

    }

    public function validate() {

        $this->load->library('user');

        if ($this->user->login() == FALSE) {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate', 'Does not match any of our database records');

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```